# OpenSSH - ssh-keygen - Generation of DH-GEX candidates at a specific start point fails

Tags: openssh

I'm playing around with `ssh-keygen` to generate new primes for **OpenSSH** for the purpose of education. The generation works when I don't pass a start point (default is a random start point according to the [man-page](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh-keygen#MODULI_GENERATION)) to `ssh-keygen`. But currently I noticed two behaviours, when I set a start point.

First behaviour (start point at 0):

```
$ ssh-keygen -M generate -O bits=2048 -O start=0 moduli.candidates
Sat Jan  2 02:04:34 2021 Sieve next 67043328 plus 2047-bit
Sat Jan  2 02:05:08 2021 Sieved with 203277289 small primes in 34 seconds
Sat Jan  2 02:05:08 2021 Found 0 candidates
```

Can somebody explain here, why this isn't working? Okay, `0` isn't a prime. But same result when I set here small primes (`2`, `3`, `5` and `7`).

Second behaviour:

```
$ ssh-keygen -M generate -O bits=2048 -O start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moduli.candidates
Sat Jan  2 02:10:21 2021 Sieve next 67043328 plus 2047-bit
Sat Jan  2 02:13:27 2021 Sieved with 203277289 small primes in 186 seconds
Sat Jan  2 02:13:35 2021 Found 56141 candidates
```

Here I used the smallest prime from a previous (working) generation and zeroed the most significant byte. The generation works, but when I want to screen this generate candidates it's also fails:

```
$ ssh-keygen -M screen -f moduli.candidates moduli.safe
Sat Jan  2 02:19:02 2021 Found 0 safe primes of 0 candidates in 0 seconds
```

The file definitly contain candidates:
*Here the first candidate:*

```
$ head moduli.candidates
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
[...]
$
```

*Here the line count:*

```
$ wc -l moduli.candidates
56141 moduli.candidates
$
```

What is the correct way to set a start point in `ssh-keygen`?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

`ssh-keygen` needs a start point with exactly a bit size minus 1. Currently `ssh-keygen` doesn't check the start point when generating, if the start point is within the range.

The correct start point ranges:
Bit size **2048**:
**0x40** to **0x7f** plus **2040** (random) bits

Bit size **4096**:
**0x40** to **0x7f** plus **4088** (random) bits

and so on...

Values lesser or greater currently works when generating candidates, but fails on screening/testing with a error message when running `ssh-keygen` in verbose mode.